# Como puedo eliminar elemenos repetidos en una lista en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esta lista que esta acá

```
vEdades = [2, 7, 58, 7, 45, 26, 10, 8, 56, 57, 97, 19, 11, 53, 3, 99, 62, 78, 29, 9, 37, 42, 56, 86, 28, 86, 95, 26, 49, 67, 21, 815, 67, 10, 58, 512, 24, 92, 89, 67, 53, 10, 9, 83, 1, 44, 10, 77, 98, 73, 57]
```

Me gustaria saber como hacer para eliminar todas las ocurrencias del entero 10, probe con vEdades.remove(10) pero solo me elimina la primera ocurrencia del entero 10

Comment: Usa una comprensión de listas para copiar todos los que no sean 10. `vEdades = [ edad for edad in vEdades if edad!=10 ]`

Comment: ¿Quieres eliminar elementos repetidos de la lista (es decir, dejar un solo "ejemplar" de cada uno)? ¿O lo que quieres es eliminar todas las apariciones de un elemento dado (ej, el 10)? Lo pregunto porque todas las respuestas que has recibido se orientan a la primera pregunta, pero creo que querías la segunda. La culpa es del título que es confuso. Yo lo retitularía así: "¿Como eliminar todas las apariciones de un elemento dado de una lista?"

Comment: `while vEdades.count(10):  vEdades.remove(10)`

Comment: @CandidMoe para listas grandes no considero tan buena idea usar esa forma. Pues implica recorrer la lista varias veces desde el principio. Yo creo que es mejor usar un bucle for e ir agregando los items que no sean iguales a 10 a la lista. O mejor aun, la comprensión de lista propuesta por Abulafia. Aun así, esta respuesta es valida para listas pequeñas, ya que el cambio de velocidad es despreciable.

Comment: @DanteS. Es un chiste, una broma, una travesura.

Comment: `vEdades = [*filter(lambda x: x != 10, vEdades)]`

Comment: @CandidMoe no me parece una broma, pero está bien, si lo dices...

Answer (score 4):

Puedes crear un [set](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), y convertirlo en lista de nuevo.

Un set es una estructura de datos que solo almacena elementos únicos (sin duplicados). **Advertencia:** Esta forma no respetará el orden de los datos de la lista.

```
vEdades = [2, 7, 58, 7, 45, 26, 10, 8, 56, 57, 97, 19, 11, 53, 3, 99, 62, 78, 29, 9, 37, 42, 56, 86, 28, 86, 95, 26, 49, 67, 21, 815, 67, 10, 58, 512, 24, 92, 89, 67, 53, 10, 9, 83, 1, 44, 10, 77, 98, 73, 57]
vEdadesUnicas = list(set(vEdades))
```

El resultado será:

> [512, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 19, 21, 24, 26, 28, 29, 37, 42, 44, 45, 815, 49, 53, 56, 57, 58, 62, 67, 73, 77, 78, 83, 86, 89, 92, 95, 97, 98, 99]

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo de muchas formas pero si estás iniciando en python te puede ser sencilla esta solución:

```
vEdades = [2, 7, 58, 7, 45, 26, 10, 8, 56, 57, 97, 19, 11, 53, 3, 99, 62, 78, 29, 9, 
37, 42, 56, 86, 28, 86, 95, 26, 49, 67, 21, 815, 67, 10, 58, 512, 24, 92, 89, 67, 53, 
10, 9, 83, 1, 44, 10, 77, 98, 73, 57]

vEdades_unicos = []
for i in vEdades:
    if i not in vEdades_unicos:
        vEdades_unicos.append(i)
```

Lo que haces es crearte una lista lista resultado, en este caso yo la llame `vEdades_unicas` lo que haces es recorrer tu lista original con un bucle `for` y dentro de este que con la condicion `if i not in vEdades_unicos`, siendo i el elemento que está iterando, si este ya está en la lista resultado, si está continua con el siguiente, si no está lo que hará es que lo va a añadir a la lista reusltado. Espero que te pueda funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es utilizar de la librería numpy la [función `unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), que elimina los elementos repetidos y a vez los ordena.

```py
import numpy a np

vEdades = [2, 7, 58, 7, 45, 26, 10, 8, 56, 57, 97, 19, 11, 53, 3, 99, 62, 78, 29, 9, 37, 42, 56, 86, 28, 86, 95, 26, 49, 67, 21, 815, 67, 10, 58, 512, 24, 92, 89, 67, 53, 10, 9, 83, 1, 44, 10, 77, 98, 73, 57]

np.unique(vEdades)
```

Devuelve

```sh
array([  1,   2,   3,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  19,  21,  24,  26,  28,
        29,  37,  42,  44,  45,  49,  53,  56,  57,  58,  62,  67,  73,
        77,  78,  83,  86,  89,  92,  95,  97,  98,  99, 512, 815])
```